# Error Notice: Undefined index al hacer un insert a una tabla php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Un saludo, estoy incursionando en la programación y estoy queriendo hacer un insert a una tabla, pero al momento de enviar la informacion, me muestra este mensaje:

Notice: Undefined index: identificacion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConexionBDPHP\validarAgregarEmpleado.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConexionBDPHP\validarAgregarEmpleado.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: fechaingreso in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConexionBDPHP\validarAgregarEmpleado.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: correo in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConexionBDPHP\validarAgregarEmpleado.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: genero in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConexionBDPHP\validarAgregarEmpleado.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: cargo in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConexionBDPHP\validarAgregarEmpleado.php on line 10
No se puedo agregar empleado

y en MySQL me muestra el campo vacío. Que puedo hacer en esta caso.

este es el codigo que estoy utilizando.

```
<?php

require "ConexionBD.php";

extract ($_REQUEST);

$objConexion = Conectarse();

$sql = "insert into empleados (empIdentificacion,empNombre,empFechaIngreso,empCorreo,empGenero,empCargo)
values('$_REQUEST[identificacion]','$_REQUEST[nombre]','$_REQUEST[fechaingreso]','$_REQUEST[correo]','$_REQUEST[genero]','$_REQUEST[cargo]')";

$resultado = $objConexion->query($sql);

if ($resultado)
    
    echo "El empleado se a agregado correctamente";
    
    else
        echo "No se puedo agregar empleado";
        
?>
```

y este es el formulario:

```
<?php

require "ConexionBD.php";

$objConexion=Conectarse();

$sql="select idCargo, carNombre from cargos";
    
    $resultado=$objConexion->query($sql);
?>
```

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Formulario Agregar Empleado</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="validarAgregarEmpleado.php">
      <table width="620" height="235" border="1" align="center">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#FFED01">AGREGAR EMPLEADO</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="296" align="right" bgcolor="#C3C3C3">Identificacion</td>
            <td width="308"><input name="identificacion" type="text" id="identificacion" maxlength="40" style="width: 270px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#C3C3C3">Nombre</td>
            <td><input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" maxlength="40" style="width: 270px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#C3C3C3">Fecha de Ingreso</td>
            <td><input name="fechaingreso" type="date" id="fechaingreso" maxlength="40" style="width: 270px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="29" align="right" bgcolor="#C3C3C3"><p>Correo</p></td>
            <td><input name="correo" type="email" id="correo" maxlength="40" style="width: 270px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#C3C3C3">Genero</td>
            <td><label for="genero">Select:</label>
              <select name="genero" id="genero" style="width: 270px">
                <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
                <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
            </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#C3C3C3">Cargo</td>
            <td><label for="cargo"></label>
              <select name="cargo" id="cargo" style="width: 270px">
                <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                  <?php
                  
                  while ($cargo = $resultado->fetch_object())
                  {
                ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cargo->idCargo?>"><?php echo $cargo->carNombre?></option>
                 
                  <?php 
                            }
                  ?>  
            </select></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="29" colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#FFEE05"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ese fallo suelo salir si una variable no está definida. Has probado cambiar tus `$_REQUEST[identificacion]` por `$identificacion`, `$nombre`, etc.. ya que al usar la función `extract()`, es decir, esta función trata a las claves como nombres de variables y a los valores como valores de variables. Por cada par clave/valor creará una variable en la tabla de símbolos actual. Luego fijando bien, también te faltan las **comillas simples** en tus **REQUEST**, es decir, `$_REQUEST['identificacion']`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ese fallo suelo salir si una variable no está definida. En tu caso fijando bien, te faltan las comillas simples `''` en tus `REQUEST` y de allí el error.

Corrección: `$_REQUEST['identificacion']`

Luego si usas la función `extract()` podrías hacer directamente *$identificacion*, *$nombre*, etc..

Ya que [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php); Importa *variables* desde un *array* a la tabla de símbolos actual.

Comprueba cada clave para ver si tiene un nombre de variable válido. También comprueba las colisiones con las variables existentes en la tabla de símbolos.

> **Advertencia:** No use `extract()` sobre datos no confiables, como la entrada del usuario (p.e. $_GET, $_FILES).

A tu ejemplo actual añadiría la función [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), es decir, escapa los caracteres especiales de una cadena para usarla en una sentencia SQL, tomando en cuenta el conjunto de caracteres actual de la conexión

Ejemplo:
`$nombre = $objConexion->real_escape_string($nombre);`

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
<?php
//Si esta definida nuestro FORM
if isset($_POST) {  
    //Importar variables a la tabla de símbolos actual desde un array
    extract($_REQUEST);

    //Comprobamos que sean verdaderos variables creados
    if ($identificacion && $nombre && $fechaingreso && $correo && $genero && $cargo) {
        //Conexión
        require "ConexionBD.php";
        $objConexion = Conectarse();

        //Escapa los caracteres especiales de una cadena para usarla en una sentencia SQL, tomando en cuenta el conjunto de caracteres actual de la conexión
        $identificacion = $objConexion->real_escape_string($identificacion);
        $nombre = $objConexion->real_escape_string($nombre);
        //etc...

        //Consulta
        $sql = "insert into empleados (empIdentificacion,empNombre,empFechaIngreso,empCorreo,empGenero,empCargo)
        values('$identificacion','$nombre','$fechaingreso','$correo','$genero','$cargo')";

        $resultado = $objConexion->query($sql);

        if ($resultado) {
            
            echo "El empleado se a agregado correctamente";
            
        }  else { echo "No se puedo agregar empleado"; }
    } else {
        #Error
    }

} else {
    #Error
}    
?>
```

Te aconsejo usar [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para mejor la seguridad de tu aplicación.